# MySQL error 1064 'mysql -u root -p qpcapps < /home/admin/appsdb.sql' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.7.41 on redhat enterprise linux 7.9

When importing a database with command

```sql
mysql -u root -p myapps < /home/admin/appsdb.sql
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p myapps < /home/admin/appsdb.sql' at line 1

According to what I've seen, this error is for a syntax error, but I don't see any wrong syntax with the command. I also made sure to use create database myapps before running the command.

Here is what the first few lines of the sql dump:

```sql
/*
SQLyog Ultimate v13.1.8 (64 bit)
MySQL - 5.1.73 : Database - myapps
*********************************************************************
*/

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`myapps` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `myapps`;
```

Comment: Looks like you access the command inside of a mysql command shell. You have to call it in your linux bash

Comment: @Jens thanks, this worked without any issues. I still needed to create the database though before running the command

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to run the command in the linux command line instead of from within a mysql command shell